# Can't update qlabel in pyqt6

Tags: qlabel, pyqt6

```
'''
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Ui, self).__init__()          
    uic.loadUi("IC7300GUI.ui", self)    


    self.frequency.setText(readFrequency())
    self.frequency.update()

    # readFrequency()  # This hasn't got any effect
    self.show()                         
'''
```

Hello,

I have created a GUI with QT and converted to `.py`, but I can't get the frequency label to update when turning the dial on my radio. The GUI starts OK and the frequency is displayed but doesn't update when it changes (while it works in the terminal with the function print()). I attempted `the.update()` `and.repaint()` functions but had no success. If I use the `tkinter` module, it works fine, but `tkinter` is missing some widgets that are useful for what I am planning to do. I have attached a picture so you can see that the frequency in the terminal is updating while the one on the label is not. I hope you can help me.

[image]

Comment: In your code there's no attempt to actually update the text. Nonetheless, your code is *extremely* long (almost 400 lines!) and this isn't really a debugging service. Please take your time to read [ask], review the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/2001654) and remember that you should always try to provide a [mre]. Finally, you're not expected to edit pyuic generated files, but instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/designer.html).

Comment: I wasn't expecting to have a debugging service, I thought to post the whole code would have make it easier to understand. Anyway, I have now created a new file where I do import the .ui directly, which is much better, I didn't realized that, grazie! However after pointing to the label the frequency still doesn't update in the GUI, so I am still stuck :-).

Comment: I have just put a snip of the code following the above suggestion.